# Why can't I do forEach on a Javascript deep cloned array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, clone

This gives me an alert for the numbers 1, 2, and 3.

```
[1,2,3].forEach(alert);
```

This gives me an error:

```
$.extend(true, {}, [1,2,3]).forEach(alert);
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'
```

Why does this happen, and how can I loop over the cloned object?

Comment: You're cloning the array to an empty Object, not another array. `forEach` is a function of the `Array` object.

Comment: `$.extend(true, [], [1,2,3]).forEach(alert);` works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Your `.extend()` call is creating an plain object, not an array. (That is, you're not actually creating a "deep cloned array".) There's no iterator like `.forEach` on plain objects.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simply because arrays `[]` have `forEach` methods, and objects `{}` do not.

If you were to have an array of objects, you could `forEach` through the array.
If you had an object, whose one property was an array, you could `forEach` through the array like `obj.arr.forEach`.
If you had an array of arrays, each of which had objects, with arrays as properties, you could set up a function which would `forEach` through the outer array, then `forEach` through the inner array's objects, then access the property of the object which held the array, and then `forEach` through that.

But you can't `{}.forEach` using vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method you want is **.each()**

Nevermind, I misread your question...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the object array, you can use,

```
var numbs = $.extend(true, {}, [1,2,3]);

for (var numb in numbs){
    alert(numbs[numb]);
}
```

Works in fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/v6KFn/